# How to add delay on mouseenter function within this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down menu, it stretches the entire width across the top of page , so when you mouse off top of page, onto your browsers menu/address bar quickly the menu will open. I want to put a slight delay on this, so the mouse will have to rest on the menu a 1/2 second before opening. This will allow me to not have this dang menu opening everytime i slide my mouse off top of page.

```
$(function(){
       $(window).resize();
       $('#navigation_horiz ul li').bind('mouseenter',function(e){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).children('.dropdown').length>0){
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id',$(this).children('.dropdown').attr('id'));    
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html($(this).children('.dropdown').html());
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').slideDown(500);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:0},0).animate({opacity:1},800,'linear');
        }
    }, 500);
    });

    jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
      return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
    };  

    $('#navigation_horiz').bind('mouseleave',function(){
        if($('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().length > 0 && $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id')=='dropdown_login' && ($('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').find('input').is(":focus") || $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').find('select').is(":focus") )){
        }else{
            $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').delay(600).slideUp(500);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:1},0).animate({opacity:0},1000,'linear');
        }
    });

    $('#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children().hide();
    $('#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children(":eq(0)").show();    
    $("#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsTabGroup li").live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent('ul').next('.TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children().hide();
        $(this).parent('ul').next('.TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children(":eq("+$(this).attr('tabindex')+")").show();
    }); 
    <!--

    //-->

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout()`

```
 var timer;
 $('#navigation_horiz ul li').bind('mouseenter',function(e){
      timer =  setTimeout(function(){
            $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if($(this).children('.dropdown').length>0){
                $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id',$(this).children('.dropdown').attr('id'));    
                $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html($(this).children('.dropdown').html());
                $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').slideDown(500);
                $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
                $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:0},0).animate({opacity:1},800,'linear');
             }
           },1000);// 1 second delay
      }
```

On mouseleave clear the timer

```
$('#navigation_horiz').bind('mouseleave',function(){
 clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: added, but menu will not open at all now, do you have a full edit of my original post to see if i'm implementing this correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this: wrap the contents of the mouse enter function in a timeout:

```
var timer;
$('#navigation_horiz ul li').bind('mouseenter',function(e){
    that = this; //'this' becomes the window when inside the setTimeout callback, so I store it in a variable 'that'
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){ //Wrap the contents of the mouse enter function in a timeout.
        $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(that).addClass('active'); // I have replace all "$(this)"'s with "$(that)"'s
        if($(that).children('.dropdown').length>0){
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id',$(this).children('.dropdown').attr('id'));    
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html($(this).children('.dropdown').html());
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').slideDown(500);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:0},0).animate({opacity:1},800,'linear');
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

You should clear the timeout on mouseleave:

```
$('#navigation_horiz').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

**Source(s)**

[MDN - window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: added to script, but menu will not even open now

Comment: @user2250423 I'm not sure why - try assigning the setTimeout to a variable (see above), this may be the problem. Also make sure not to copy 7 paste my code, because then you're relying on me to not make typo's (which I do frequently ;) )

Comment: sorry, but i'm clueless to js/jquery , so unless it's a copy/paste i have no idea what i'm doing

Comment: did again...nothing...I edited my original question with your change, do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: will put it in jfiddle, give me a minute